# PhantomJS Change JS src before he starts loading

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, dom-manipulation

I'trying to change Javascript *src* in order to get a "dev environment" for testing some Javascripts.

( *Obviously i can't build a **real** dev environment , i can't mirror this website on a dev  env* ).

So i was thinking about manipulating Dom with PhantomJS and testing javascript with CasperJS. I wanna convert ( for example ) this script

`<script type="..." language="..." src="production_path/source.js"></script>`

into this one

`<script type="..." language="..." src="dev_path/source.js"></script>`

before the script starts loading.

I'm trying with

```
casper.start("http://www.example.com/",function(status){


        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

        casper.each(scripts,function(self,my_script){

            //here i would rewrite script url

        });

});

casper.run();
```

but it doesn't work. I'm afraid i have to wait for something , but i'm not understanding what.

Comment: @ArtjomB. proxy was the option i want to skip :-)

Comment: You can do basically what I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25261331/1816580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a step back, is it okay to re-phrase your question as: how do I get PhantomJS to load "dev_path/source.js" when it tries to load "production_path/source.js"?

If so, write a [`onResourceRequested`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-requested.html) handler, and use the `changeUrl` function of the `resourceRequest` object.

It will be something like this:

```
casper.page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, networkRequest) {
  if(requestData.url == 'production_path/source.js'){
    console.log("Changing request from production to dev for source.js");
    networkRequest.changeUrl('dev_path/source.js');
    }
};
```

Of course in a real situation I'd use a regex replace (as I expect there are multiple URLs to replace).

(Untested, so let me know if it does not work, and I'll look into it more carefully.)

Comment: It Works, just a comment... this is the code used by me: `casper.on('resource.requested',function(requestData,networkRequest){....});`